# how to rebuild a widget built from a function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that I intend to reuse in various sections of my app.

```
Widget getTextField({required String hint,required IconData icon, required int minLength,required StringValue callback}){
 return CupertinoTextField(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    prefix: Padding(
        padding: iconPadding,
        child: Icon(icon)),
    suffix: Padding(
        padding: iconPadding,
        child: Icon(_length >= minLength ? Icons.check_circle : Icons.check_circle_outline)),
    placeholder: hint,
    onChanged: (text){
      _length = text.length;
       callback(text);
 
    },
  );

}
```

When I tried to reuse a state-full widget I had a problem that if I typed in one textfield the rest had the same text popping in, which means that the same instance of the widget was being used. Using the `new` keyword did not help as well.

The above approach worked as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63424310/8528047

However the icon is not being changed when the boolean value `_length` becomes true.
How do I make the widget rebuild itself when the boolean condition changes ?

Comment: did you try callBack method, if your function on different widget, if in same widget, you will get `setstate()`. also i prefer `stateManagement`

Comment: what callback method ? can you please explain.

Comment: like use a function as parameter and add it on `onChanged`

Comment: Don't know how I would do that. can you post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a simple `Widget` class and pass arguments to that, for example:

```dart
class GetTextFieldWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final EdgeInsets iconPadding;
  final int minLength;
  final ValueChanged onChanged;
  final IconData icon;
  final String hint;

  const GetTextFieldWidget(this.iconPadding, this.minLength, this.onChanged,this.icon, this.hint);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _GetTextFieldWidget();
}

class _GetTextFieldWidget extends State<GetTextFieldWidget> {
  final int _length = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTextField(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      prefix: Padding(
        padding: widget.iconPadding,
        child: Icon(widget.icon),
      ),
      suffix: Padding(
          padding: widget.iconPadding,
          child: Icon(_length >= widget.minLength ? Icons.check_circle : Icons.check_circle_outline)),
      placeholder: widget.hint,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Put a few of these widgets in a column and type in one of them. All of them get filled up with the same text. How do I avoid that. ?